# why can't I create comment using rules?

Tags: 7, rules, comments

Simple rule:

after update node: create new entity with type: "comment"

but after update node, nothing happens...

why that?

UPD, added screenshots of my rule:

[image]

UPD2: i can create node by creating entity, but not a comment o_O

UPD3: **ok understand what is the problem: i called the content type(machine name) 'task'** =)

[image]

UPD4: errors while updating node and creating comment:
[image]
full error message: "Unable to get variable entity_created, it is not defined."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you did not save it.

Add action of `Save Entity`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't work -(

Comment: @OnengLar you need to select `Force saving immediately: True`

Comment: yes, i have tried both

Comment: @OnengLar should've worked. You sure you are testing/updating in the right content type (Task)?

Comment: yes, i have only one content type

Comment: and you are **updating** the node, not creating a new one? right...? Comments are enabled? (you see the comment box?) and node author have permission to comment?

Comment: >>> "updating the node" yes, >>> "Comments are enabled" yes, >>> "see the comment box" yes, >>> "have permission to comment" yes =)

Comment: @OnengLar feel free to login to my test site https://dg2kz.ply.st/node/1 `User: OnengLar Pass: OnengLar` as you can see it works. So perhaps you have some custom or some other contrib module that is causing your problem.

Comment: ok in your website work fine, it's weird, i'l try later on another server...
Thanks you

Comment: @OnengLar maybe your rule is disabled? Make sure it's listed under `Active rules` and not `Innactive Rules` in /admin/config/workflow/rules

Comment: rule is active, when i change machine name to anything not 'task'  comments creates Ok oO

Comment: Does anything show in the error log `/admin/reports/dblog`?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens thanks for the heads up, but nothing in comments is crucial.